# Одинарные кавычки в echo php

Tags: php

Я новичок в PHP, не могу понять как использовать одинарные кавычки дважды (в echo и коде).

Вот пример:

```
echo '<div class="item" style="background-image: url("' . esc_url($large_image_url[0]) . '");">';
echo '</div>';
```

Мне нужно чтобы в background-image: url(" - вместо двойной кавычки использовалась одинарная. Но если её проставить то код уедет.

Надеюсь, вы меня поймете ибо не знаю, как ещё изложить свои мысли на этот счет..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариант 1: экранирование

```
echo '<div class=\'item\' style=\'background-image: url(\'' .esc_url($large_image_url[0]) . '\');\'></div>';
```

Вариант 2: поменять местами с двойными

```
echo "<div class='item' style='background-image: url('" . esc_url($large_image_url[0]) . "');'></div>";
```

Comment: Будда поведал мне, что двойные кавычки работают медленнее одинарных. :) По крайней мере когда я писал раньше на php (v4-5), даже во всех доках по оптимизации писали почему. Это утверждение ещё остается верным?

Comment: Боюсь, второй вариант кроме теоретического "замедления" выдаст неверную HTML разметку

Comment: Добавьте вариант `sprintf`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Это утверждение больше неверно.

Comment: @E_p чем подкуёте? В php7 убрали возможность в двойных кавычках писать переменные типа `$helloMsg = "Hello $userName"`? Если нет, то почему неверно?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев https://jonczyk.me/2016/10/23/phpyths-buster-great-string-performance-test/ Скорость давно починили.

Comment: @E_p круто, спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вставить одинарные ковычки внутрь одинарных и аналогично с двойными нужно их экранировать, вот так:

```
echo '<div class="item" style=\'background-image: url(' . esc_url($large_image_url[0]) . ');\'>';
echo '</div>';
```